# Chef Template Does Not Evaluate chef_environment and name Correctly

Tags: ruby, templates, chef-infra

```
knife node show -l my-node -F json
```

returns:

```
{
   "name": "my-node",
   "chef_environment": "test"
   ..
}
```

We have created a template, info.txt.erb:

```
node = <%= node %>
name = <%= node['name'] %>
chef_environment = <%= node['chef_environment'] %>
```

Our recipe:

```
template "#{app_dir}/info.txt" do
  source 'info.txt.erb'
  ...
end
```

After the chef run, the node has an info.txt file:

```
node = my-node
name =
chef_environment =
```

Why does the `knife show <NODE>` command return something different than what is evaluated by the template file? How can I change the template file to get the correct information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be `node.name` and `node.chef_environment`. They aren't attributes, so you can't use the attribute access syntax to get them.

Comment: This works, but I was wondering if you know where this is documented? The output of 'knife node show' does not make it clear that these are not attributes.

Comment: If you look at the expanded view it's easier to see (i.e. `knife node show --long`), things that are attributes are all under the various attribute level keys while the name and environment (and run list, etc) are not.

Comment: That is a good, simple explanation - I wish that I could have found something similar in the documentation.